# AJAX: success not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a button that disables itself when uploading an image, the opload is done using AJAX. But the success callback is not working, (I can tell because not even the console show its content in `console.log`. What am I doing wrong?

I changed the url part, now Iḿ receiving this on the console : POST http://192.168.0.229:8000/feed/add 419 (unknown status)

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-type-image]', function () {
    $('#image_upload').click();
    var formData = new FormData($(document));
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        beforeSend: function () {
            console.log('before send working');
            $('form').find('div').find('button').attr('disabled', true);
            $('form').find('div').find('button').css('background-color', 'grey');
        },
        success: function(){
            console.log('success working');
            $('form').find('div').find('button').attr('disabled', false);
            $('form').find('div').find('button').removeAttr('style');
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log(error);
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: function () {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) { // Avalia se tem suporte a propriedade upload
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {

                }, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Its may be due to some error checks your console

Comment: POST http://192.168.0.229:8000/feed/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This is the error on the console

Comment: Now that the error changed, please edit your question with the new information

Answer (score 1):

`$(document)` returns a jQuery object, instead you want to pass to ajax url attribute a string containing the url of the endpoint. Supposing you want to perform a `POST` request in the same endpoint wich returns the view where button exists.

Replace

```
url: $(document),
```

with

```
url: window.location.href,
```

**EDIT:** (Error changed from 500 to 419)

Ajax success callback needs a successful HTTP response (like 200, 302...). If backend doesn't send a successful response to client after a `POST` request, it is expected to receive a 419 error: the endpoint exists, but there's no return action for a `POST` request, only for `GET`, in which a view is returned.

Comment: I changed and got this in the console

Comment: If you check Network tab and click on the request, you will be able to see more details of the error (response). Can you check it for us?

Comment: Click in the request name, then preview tab

Comment: {message: ""}
message
:
""

Comment: That's the only thing in the preview tab

Comment: What's expected in the server side to do with a POST request? Do you know about that?

Comment: Ajax success callback needs a successful HTTP response (like 200, 302...).  If backend doesn't send a successful response to client after a POST request, it is expected to receive a 419 error: the endpoint exists, but there's no return action for a POST request, only for GET, in which a view is returned.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, but I think it just expects the image

Comment: Do you understand what I told about the backend problem?

Comment: Changing to GET actually solved 'part' of the problem

Comment: now it's executing all at once, the button disables, but it enables again right away

Comment: while the image is still loading

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a valid url for Ajax to work.
see the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
url should be a valid url string. you are passing *$(document)* which is an object.
look at the network tab in dev tool if request is going to server or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is code can give you the index but first you need  select the word.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(
function(){

$("#id1").click(function(){

var txt = $("#id1").val();
var test= txt.split(" ")
$(test).each(function(item){
if(test[item]==window.getSelection()){
alert( item);
}

});

});
});

</script>
<input type="text" id="id1" value="10" />
```